# Как настроить Windows, чтобы принимались во внимание физические размеры экранов?

Tags: windows-10, монитор

Есть экран ноутбука [1] и экран монитора [2].

[1]
14'', 1920x1080

[2]
27'', 2560x1440

Графический процессор размеры сторон (диагональ) определяет правильно. Разрешение установлено корректное. Однако Windows считает, что [1] относительно [2] гораздо больше, чем это есть на самом деле. Как результат - неудобство использования экрана ноутбука, т.к. курсор неистово скачет при переходе с одного монитора на другой.

[image: Графическое объяснение проблемы на фото]

На картинке видно, что фактически высота [1] составляет чуть больше половины от [2] (зелёная стрелка). Однако комп считает иначе (красная полоска). Как с этим бороться?

Пробовал уменьшать разрешение экрана ноутбука - естественно "помогает", т.к. Windows начинает его видеть более маленьким. Однако, естественно, это не решение проблемы. Хотелось бы пользоваться экранами с их родным разрешением (максимальным).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас PPI отличается в полтора раза. 157.35 PPI против 108.79 PPI.
Нативно с этим никак не жить, но есть решение — [LittleBigMouse](https://github.com/mgth/LittleBigMouse)

Comment: Это то, что я искал. Спасибо)

Comment: @yaroslav-hub как вариант ещё, чтобы дополнительный софт не ставить, такое вот ещё [решение через Nvidia](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KNofwZRuHho&t=72s) нашёл. Но не бесшовное. LMB лучше, если установка 3rd party не смущает.